# Is using `ref` in a function argument the same as automatically taking a reference?

Tags: rust

Rust tutorials often advocate passing an argument by reference:

```
fn my_func(x: &Something)
```

This makes it necessary to explicitly take a reference of the value at the call site:

```
my_func(&my_value).
```

It is possible to use the `ref` keyword usually used in pattern matching:

```
fn my_func(ref x: Something)
```

I can call this by doing

```
my_func(my_value)
```

Memory-wise, does this work like I expect or does it copy `my_value` on the stack before calling `my_func` and then get a reference to the copy?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The value is copied, and the copy is then referenced.

```
fn f(ref mut x: i32) {
    *x = 12;
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 42;
    f(x);
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

Output: 42

Answer (score 8):

Both functions declare `x` to be `&Something`. The difference is that the former takes a reference as the parameter, while the latter expects it to be a regular stack value. To illustrate:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Something;

fn by_reference(x: &Something) {
    println!("{:?}", x); // prints "&Something""
}

fn on_the_stack(ref x: Something) {
    println!("{:?}", x); // prints "&Something""
}

fn main() {
    let value_on_the_stack: Something = Something;
    let owned: Box<Something> = Box::new(Something);
    let borrowed: &Something = &value_on_the_stack;

    // Compiles:
    on_the_stack(value_on_the_stack);

    // Fail to compile:
    // on_the_stack(owned);
    // on_the_stack(borrowed);

    // Dereferencing will do:
    on_the_stack(*owned);
    on_the_stack(*borrowed);

    // Compiles:
    by_reference(owned); // Does not compile in Rust 1.0 - editor
    by_reference(borrowed);

    // Fails to compile:
    // by_reference(value_on_the_stack);

    // Taking a reference will do:
    by_reference(&value_on_the_stack);
}
```

Since `on_the_stack` takes a value, it gets copied, then the copy matches against the pattern in the formal parameter (`ref x` in your example). The match binds `x` to the reference to the copied value.

Comment: "Since *on_the_stack* takes a value, it gets copied" <-- `Something` type doesn't implement `Copy`, so it gets *moved*. Probably better to say "passed-by-value" instead of either copy/moved

Answer (score 5):

If you call a function like `f(x)` then `x` is always passed by value.

```
fn f(ref x: i32) {
    // ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
fn f(tmp: i32) {
    let ref x = tmp;
    // or,
    let x = &tmp;

    // ...
}
```

i.e. the referencing is completely restricted to the function call.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between your two functions becomes much more pronounced and obvious if the value doesn't implement `Copy`. For example, a `Vec<T>` doesn't implement `Copy`, because that is an expensive operation, instead, it implements `Clone` (Which requires a specific method call).

Assume two methods are defined as such

```
fn take_ref(ref v: Vec<String>) {}// Takes a reference, ish
fn take_addr(v: &Vec<String>) {}// Takes an explicit reference
```

`take_ref` will try to copy the value passed, before referencing it. For `Vec<T>`, this is actually a move operation (Because it doesn't copy). This actually consumes the vector, meaning the following code would throw a compiler error:

```
let v: Vec<String>; // assume a real value
take_ref(v);// Value is moved here
println!("{:?}", v);// Error, v was moved on the previous line
```

However, when the reference is explicit, as in `take_addr`, the `Vec` isn't moved but passed by reference. Therefore, this code does work as intended:

```
let v: Vec<String>; // assume a real value
take_addr(&v);
println!("{:?}", v);// Prints contents as you would expect
```